# Validating both K and its converse

Tags: modal-logic

Consider a system of modal logic that validates both of the axioms below.

: ◻(→)→(◻→◻)

′: (◻→◻)→◻(→)

Could you please explain in simple words what would this system look like? I guess there would be some kind of trivialization going on.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2398286/converse-of-axiom-k